# Grabbing links of header/footer of webpages

Tags: html, vba, selenium

I try to get all links of the header of a `HTMLDocument` to process them.
Therefore I use:

```
Dim docHTML As New HTMLDocument
Dim docElements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim docElement As IHTMLElement
Dim sPageSource as String

    docHTML.body.innerHTML = sPageSource

    set docElement = docHTML.getElementsByTagName("header")(0)
    set docElements = docElement.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

But the links aren't in `docElements`. The length is zero. What is wrong here?
I can't use a specific specific id or classname, because the values are changing depending on the website I read. I have to exclude links from `data-target`, which is defined in one of the parents.

Any ideas?

As alternative I tried Selenium. With that code:

```
Dim aData As Selenium.WebElements
Dim htmlElement As Selenium.WebElement

    Set htmlElement = bot.FindElementByTag("header")
    Set aData = htmlElement.FindElementsByTag("a")
```

Here I get all links of header, but I have no possibility to get information about the parents.

I would prefer the first approach, because I have the impression that Selenium is slower with data handling.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the HTML code. Perhaps print out `docElement.outerhtml` so that you can see what is in it.

Comment: The outerhtml shows `<HEADER id=atIdViewHeader>`
I'll find with `htmlElement.nextsibling.nextsibling` the closing tag `</header>`.

Comment: I do not know how many siblings there are till the closing tag. Do I have the possibility to get the complete tag?

Comment: What element do you see for `docElement.nextSibling.nodename`?

Comment: Perhaps do a `Do While docElement.NodeName <> "</HEADER>": If docElement.NodeName = "A" Then [do things]: Set docElement = docElement.nextSibling: Loop`

Comment: Hello Raymond, thanks you that works.